# When partitioning with Gparted how do I create a 1 gigabyte partition?

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, lubuntu, gparted

I'm using Lubuntu 13.10 amd64bit. I have Gparted installed, but how can I make a 1 gigabyte partition? It says MiB.

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone uses gigabyte with the same meaning. Gigabyte can mean 1 000 000 000 bytes, or 1 073 741 824 bytes.
Personally I use the IEC standard in which a gigabyte equates to 1 000 000 000 bytes, and a gibibyte is 1 073 741 824 bytes. Ubuntu
also officially uses this standard.

**Steps:**

Option #1 = If you consider a gigabyte to be 1 073 741 824 bytes, then input 1024 MiB in Gparted.

Option #2 = If you consider a gigabyte to be 1 000 000 000 bytes, as Ubuntu officially does then input 954 MiB [Which is slightly over as it should be 953.67431640625 MiB]

**Useful Information:**

If you consider a gigabyte to be 1 000 000 000 bytes then you can use parted to verify the size after partitioning in Gparted.

```
"sudo parted -l"
```

This will list the disk and partition sizes in gigabytes or megabytes with the assumption that 1 000 000 000 bytes is a gigabyte.

Screenshot of this = https://copy.com/NL3KZjzQRsre

**Notes:**

I believe Windows operating systems refer to a gigabyte as 1 073 741 824 bytes, as in this rather old article they refer
to divisions by 1024 rather than 1000. Things may be different now as this article is pre-NT. #h#t#t#p#://support.microsoft.com/kb/121839

**Sources:**

http://postbin.djun.net/pages/article19/page.php

h#t#t#p#s#://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy

Comment: I don't have Windows so I'll use Ubuntu way (option #2). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

MiB stands for mebibyte (1,048,576 bytes) - so you need 1024MiB to create 1 gigabyte.

Nobody means "1,000,000,000" when they say "gigabyte", other than some hard-disk manufacturers when they're telling you drive capacities, and you'd never need to type that in anyplace - so whatever you think you mean by "1gb": it is 99.9% likely to be 1024 MiB and not anything else.